# In Google Chart geochart Tooltip does't show all values and marker color has changed

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, google-maps, google-visualization

[image: First image is world image where tooltip is missing country name and color is different. I want first image as second one.]

[image: Data of country]

In Google geochart First image shows world map where tooltip is missing country name and 
 color is different. Where as second image is perfectly drawn, I want first image as second. 
 This is how it works First you click on country marker and it will show 
 client of state of that country.
 Data from backend is perfect, while ploting map it get messy.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
       'packages': ['geochart'],
      'mapsApiKey': "{{env('GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY')}}"
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initMap);
function initMap() {
    var country_name = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "{{ url('dashboard/getcountrynames') }}" ,
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    success: function (jsondata){
        }
        }).responseText;
        console.log(country_name);
   var countries = $.parseJSON(country_name);
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(countries);

     var options = {
        width: 280,
        height: 180,
        chartArea: {'width': '90%', 'height': '100%'},
        displayMode: 'markers',
        sizeAxis: { minSize: 5, maxSize: 5 },
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#33ADFF', '#003D66']},
        datalessRegionColor: '#CDD9EA',
        legend: 'none',
       // tooltip: {isHtml: true}
 };
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e) { 
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
if (selection.length) {
   var clickedRegion= data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);

  var JsonData =   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
                url: "{{ url('dashboard/countrynametocode') }}/" + clickedRegion,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (jsondata) {
                $('#country_table').hide();
                $('#city_table').show();
                var code = jsondata[0].fatca_code;
                    options.region = code;
                    options.resolution = "provinces";  
                    options.showZoomOut = true;
                    options.keepAspectRatio = true;
                    options.displayMode= 'markers';

        var cityname = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{{url('dashboard/cityname')}}/" + code,
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (city) {  
        }
   }).responseText;

   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{{url('dashboard/country_name')}}/" + code,
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (city) {  
             $('#city_table').html(city);

         }
   }).responseText;

   var array1 = $.parseJSON(cityname);
   var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array1);
   chart.draw(data1, options);
     } 
     }).responseText;
    }
});
chart.draw(data, options);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution, problem was in database, datatype given to the client variable is integer to which i have change it to double. And now it is working perfectly.